# select next record against particular ID

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have following table structure:

```
MID     AutoID     MikatName

1         3           ABC

4         17          XYZ

9         20          MNS

15        26          MNVS
```

Now i want to form a query so that i can get or select next record against particular AutoID.

Means what query i have to form if i want record next to autoID 17. i.e. it is MID=9 AutoID=20 MikatName=MNS

I tried forming it as:

```
select * from ejamatPass where AutoID>17
```

But it gives me all the 2 records having autoID grater that 17. I wanted just next record to AutoID 17.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a `limit` clause and `order by`:

```
select *
from ejamatPass
where AutoID>17
order by AutoID
limit 1;
```

By the way, SQL tables are inherently unordered.  When you do a `select` there is no guarantee on the order of the results returned.  You need an `order by` to ensure ordering.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM ejamatPass WHERE AutoID>17 ORDER BY AutoID ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 (*) from ejamatPass 
where AutoID > 17
Order by AutoID
```

Comment: No you can't, not in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SELECT TOP clause.

```
select top 1 * from ejamatPass where AutoID>17
```

Comment: No you can't, not in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from ejamatPass where where AutoID>17
order by AutoID
```